# How do i write regex pattern for a String to identify numbers that precedes space or hypen?

Tags: java, regex

I have a free flowing string that has some random text like below:

- `"Some random text 080 2668215901"`
- `"Some ramdom text 040-1234567890"`
- `"Some random text 0216789101112"`

I need to capture the the 3 digit numbers and the following 10 digit numbers:

- with space condition
- with hypen condition
- without any space/hypen

I am using Java.

This is what I tried to get the numbers from the free flowing text:

```
"\\w+([0-9]+)\\w+([0-9]+)"
```

I can do a string length check to see if there are any 3 digit numbers that precedes a Hypen or a space, which is then followed by a 10 digit number.But i really would like to explore if regex can give me a better solution.

Also,if there are more occurances within the String,i'd need to capture them all. I would also need to capture any 10 digit String as well,that **need not** precede a hypen and a space

Comment: What does "with a space condition" mean?

Comment: You want to capture first 3 digits and the following 10 digits or you want to validate pattern?

Comment: The condition which has a space (" ").. In the example,its the first scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a longer demo. From your responses above you're also looking for matches with trailing chars after the match.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Class {
  private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("" +
    "((?<threeDigits>\\d{3})[- ]?)?" +
    "(?<tenDigits>\\d{10})");

  public static void main(String... args) {
    final String input =
      "Here is some text to match: Some random text 080 2668215901. " +
        "We're now matching stray sets of ten digit as well: 1234567890. " +
        "Notice how you get the first ten and the second ten, with the preceding three:1234123412-040-1234567890" +
        "A stranger case:111222333444555666777888. Where should matches here begin and end?";
    printAllMatches(p.matcher(input));
  }

  private static void printAllMatches(final Matcher m) {
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("three digits: " + m.group("threeDigits"));
      System.out.println("ten digits: " + m.group("tenDigits"));
    }
  }

}
```

switched to findall battleplan.

Comment: Thanks Andreas,i can try it on my sample. But does \\D? include just the spaces and the hypen?

Comment: Thanks Andreas,this really helps.How do we ignore the tabs though?Also,do in the 1st scenrio, if i want to include the 10 digit number along with the other,how does my regex change?

Comment: Thanks Andreas,this really helps.How do we ignore the tabs though?Also,in the 1st scenrio, if i want to include the 10 digit number along with the other,how does my regex change?

Also,regarding the edge cases you mentioned,yeah i would need to return both the numbers. for 123-8908908908-456-1231231231.

So just to summarize,

"Some random text 1234123412 080 2668215901 abracadabra 1234567890", must return 1234123412 and 1234567890.

"What if you have two valid answers: 123-8908908908-456-1231231231? What should be returned"}; 8908908908 and 1231231231 must be returned.

Comment: "What if you have two valid answers: 123-8908908908-456 with some string here and one more number 080-1231231231? 
8908908908 and 1231231231 must be retured

Comment: Awesome!That works!

Regarding the stranger case,is it possible to ignore that number completely since its not a 3 digit followed by a hiphen/space/10 digit number ,nor is it a standalone 10 digit number?

Answer (score 2):

It is usually `(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{10})`
With boundary conditions maybe  `(?<!\d)(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{10})(?!\d)`

Comment: I tried this with the string :abce 3343444888 333 3344556677 bcbcb. I did not get any results :(

Comment: ` **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 17 , len 14 ) 333 3344556677   **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 17 , len 3 ) 333   **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 21 , len 10 ) 3344556677  `

Comment: @Paul  `\s` also matches tab, line feed and other characters in the whitespace character class.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger sry, misinterpreted the question

Comment: @Paul no need to be sorry, I just wanted to have it noted; actually maybe it is required by OP

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll run this regex on individual lines, and ignoring some of the... more expressive regex implementations, this is perhaps the simplest way:

```
/([0-9]{3})[ -]?([0-9]{10})/
```

If your text might end in numbers, you'll need to anchor the result to the end of the line like this:

```
/([0-9]{3})[ -]?([0-9]{10})$/
```

If you are guaranteed literal double quote characters around your inputs, you could instead use:

```
/([0-9]{3})[ -]?([0-9]{10})"$/
```

And if you needed to match the entire line for some input error testing, you could use:

```
/^"(.+)([0-9]{3})[ -]?([0-9]{10})"$/
```